# NMaximize::cvdiv Warning Solution

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to use NMaximize to find the maximum value of variables in a function while satisfying the given constraints.
I have checked the formula and it is correct but i am getting "NMaximize::cvdiv: Failed to converge to a solution. The function may be unbounded."
Also the estimated values of the variables is not desirable.
The code is as follows:

```
NMaximize[{Sum[Log[Exp[(-b)*((1 - c)^\[Alpha] + (1 - c*Exp[-((-Log[v1[[i]]])^\[Theta] + (-Log[v2[[i]]])^\[Theta])^(1/\[Theta])])^\[Alpha] - (1 - c*v1[[i]])^\[Alpha] - (1 - c*v2[[i]])^\[Alpha])]] - 
     Log[1 + v1[[i]]*b*\[Alpha]*c*(1 - v1[[i]])^(\[Alpha] - 1)] - Log[1 + v2[[i]]*b*\[Alpha]*c*(1 - v2[[i]])^(\[Alpha] - 1)] + 
     Log[(2*b*\[Alpha]*c*(1 - c*Exp[-((-Log[v1[[i]]])^\[Theta] + (-Log[v2[[i]]])^\[Theta])^(1/\[Theta])])^(\[Alpha] - 1) + b^2*\[Alpha]^2*c^2*Exp[-((-Log[v1[[i]]])^\[Theta] + (-Log[v2[[i]]])^\[Theta])^(1/\[Theta])]*
          (1 - c*Exp[-((-Log[v1[[i]]])^\[Theta] + (-Log[v2[[i]]])^\[Theta])^(1/\[Theta])])^(2*\[Alpha] - 2) + b*\[Alpha]*c^2*Exp[-((-Log[v1[[i]]])^\[Theta] + (-Log[v2[[i]]])^\[Theta])^(1/\[Theta])]*
          (1 - c*Exp[-((-Log[v1[[i]]])^\[Theta] + (-Log[v2[[i]]])^\[Theta])^(1/\[Theta])])^(\[Alpha] - 2) - b*\[Alpha]^2*c^2*Exp[-((-Log[v1[[i]]])^\[Theta] + (-Log[v2[[i]]])^\[Theta])^(1/\[Theta])]*
          (1 - c*Exp[-((-Log[v1[[i]]])^\[Theta] + (-Log[v2[[i]]])^\[Theta])^(1/\[Theta])])^(\[Alpha] - 2))*(((-Log[v1[[i]]])^(-1 + \[Theta])*((-Log[v1[[i]]])^\[Theta] + (-Log[v2[[i]]])^\[Theta])^(-1 + 1/\[Theta]))/
         (E^((-Log[v1[[i]]])^\[Theta] + (-Log[v2[[i]]])^\[Theta])^(1/\[Theta])*v1[[i]]))*((((-Log[v1[[i]]])^\[Theta] + (-Log[v2[[i]]])^\[Theta])^(-1 + 1/\[Theta])*(-Log[v2[[i]]])^(-1 + \[Theta]))/
         (E^((-Log[v1[[i]]])^\[Theta] + (-Log[v2[[i]]])^\[Theta])^(1/\[Theta])*v2[[i]])) - (-1 - b*\[Alpha]*c*Exp[-((-Log[v1[[i]]])^\[Theta] + (-Log[v2[[i]]])^\[Theta])^(1/\[Theta])]*
          (1 - c*Exp[-((-Log[v1[[i]]])^\[Theta] + (-Log[v2[[i]]])^\[Theta])^(1/\[Theta])])^(\[Alpha] - 1))*(((1/(v1[[i]]*v2[[i]]))*(-Log[v1[[i]]])^(-1 + \[Theta])*(-1 + \[Theta] + ((-Log[v1[[i]]])^\[Theta] + (-Log[v2[[i]]])^\[Theta])^(1/\[Theta]))*
          ((-Log[v1[[i]]])^\[Theta] + (-Log[v2[[i]]])^\[Theta])^(-2 + 1/\[Theta])*(-Log[v2[[i]]])^(-1 + \[Theta]))/E^((-Log[v1[[i]]])^\[Theta] + (-Log[v2[[i]]])^\[Theta])^(1/\[Theta]))], {i, 1, n}], 
   Inequality[0, Less, \[Alpha], LessEqual, 1] && b > 0 && 0 <= c <= 1 && Inequality[Infinity, Greater, \[Theta], GreaterEqual, 1]}, {\[Alpha], b, c, \[Theta]}]
```

I tried changing the brackets or the overall format of the formula but still getting the same warning.